# ... and there was an upbeat, if determined, mood

Tags: grammar

I am reading news from BBC and I don't understand "...  and there was an upbeat, if determined, mood..." in the article.

The whole paragraph is as the following.

"The crowd was diverse - with people of different ethnicities, and families with children - and there was an upbeat, if determined, mood. Music was being played and food, water and hand sanitiser handed out, as protesters chanted "George Floyd", "Breonna Taylor" - who also died in police custody, in March - and "No justice, no peace"."

Comment: What do you think it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "if" in "if determined", is "even though".

[Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if) 4th definition of "if" is

> 4: even though : although perhaps an interesting if untenable argument

At the same time, they were upbeat - enthusiastic, full of hopeful energy - even though determined. It's not an aimless energy, but grounded on a determination for change. Conversely, it's not a grim, gloomy determination, but infused with enthusiasm and energy.

Answer (score 0):

It means "the mood was upbeat, but also determined". An alternative phrasing could be "there was an upbeat, and yet determined, mood"

Answer (score 0):

yes... I would say the 'if' is operating as a figure of speech.  To me, it implies "I might even go so far as to say..."

IMHO, it suggests a muted, if humble excitement.